# Unable to query with selectors inside auto-binding-dart templates in Dart-Polymer

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Looking at similar issues, I realize a possible solution is to use MutationObservers, but my use-case seems to add more complexity.

**Dart code :**

```
class MyModel extends Object with Observable {
@observable num x = 0;
List list = toObservable([]);
}

void main() {

  initPolymer().run(() {
      Polymer.onReady.then((_) {
        var template = querySelector("#bindValueTemplate");
        var model = template.model = new MyModel();

         var tbl = querySelector("#viewtbl");

         new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
          tbl.children.clear();
          model.x += 1;
          model.list.add(model.x);
          return model.x;
        });
     });
  });

}
```

HTML code :

```
<body> 
<template id="bindValueTemplate" is="auto-binding-dart">

<p>x = {{ x }}</p>
<ul>
  <template repeat ="{{item in list}}">
    <li>list item = {{item}}</li>
  </template>
</ul>   

<table class="table" id="viewtbl">
  <tr>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>b9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</template>
</body>
```

As seen in the dart code, I want to delete the child elements of the table #viewtbl periodically (I have not included the code which is supposed to add data to the table dynamically). But with the current code, I am getting an exception as the table variable (tbl) remains null always.

If I move the table outside of the "bindValueTemplate", then the querySelector would work, but I would lose data binding with that table.

Can someone please help me with :

1. A solution where I retain 2 way data binding with table elements alongwith querySelector access to delete child elements to table.
2. The reason why is querySelector returning null if table is inside template, but works if table is outside template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer needs some air to breathe.
When you set the model this doesn't mean that the elements are already created. I don't know but I assume this is done async.
Try it this way:

```dart
void main() {

  initPolymer().run(() {
    Polymer.onReady.then((_) {
      var template = querySelector("#bindValueTemplate");
      var model = template.model = new MyModel();

      new Future(() { // <== make async to allow Polymer do its async tasks in between
        var tbl = querySelector("#viewtbl");

        new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
          tbl.children.clear();
          model.x += 1;
          model.list.add(model.x);
          return model.x;
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Not working :( I dont know why but shadowdom is null. I tried template.shadowRoot.olderShadowRoot.querySelector('#viewtbl'); but template.shadowRoot returns null

Comment: What has shadowDOM/shadowRoot to do with it? Shadow DOM exists only when you build a custom element (Polymer element).

Comment: Looking at the other answer, I assumed I need to access viewtbl through template's shadow DOM, but shadow DOM or not, it's unable to find the viewtbl element. Using Futures didn't help. I also tried querying after a simulated delay of 5 seconds, but querySelector still returns null.

Comment: It worked fine for me here https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/test/core_input.dart#L51-L68, https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/test/core_input.html#L26-L28

Comment: @SlowAndSteady Did you finally find out what was wrong? I am having the same issue... :'(

Comment: Polymer.onReady isn't the right event for me, i need to put an additionnal delay... In a standard use of polymer we would override the ready() function of the polymer element, how can we do this here? :?

Comment: @Vloz, sorry for the delay. My issue was resolved simply by putting querySelector in a Future block as answered by Gunter. You can add another question with your code and I would try my best to help !

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you only have to create an actual polymer element. And Then you can use `$` to query for elements via their ids in the shadowdom (it's a map). I am also wondering about the notation you are using for your polymer element.
2. The reason is that querySelector() queries the regular DOM not the Shadow DOM inside .

Regards,
Robert

Comment: Thanks ! But I cant get it to work with shadow dom also. I tried template.shadowRoot.olderShadowRoot.querySelector('#viewtbl'); but template.shadowRoot returns null